# Encode/Decode a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping, html-encode

I use Asp.Net 4, C# and MS SQL.

For my website I use MS default solution for preventing Cross-Site Scripting.

I'm also used to ENCODE all User's Inputs in my logic so that this data can be stored ENCODED in my Data Base.

At the moment I'm using a GridView to do some basic CRUD operation but I'm facing a problem.

- CREATE:  User can insert any inputs, my logic will ENCODE and save on Data Base.
- READ:    The GridView can display the User's Input from Data Base in a "Label" the result is DECODED thanks to the Properties for the Field "HtmlEnscape True or False.
- UPDATE:  Here my problem! At time of editing the TextBox show up the User input from the DataBase Encoded (in this way was saved) but I would need to DECODED again to show it up to the User so can be edited in a friendly way and resaved.

My questions:
- How to do it?
- Because I have many TextBox in many pages in my application, how to centralize this behavior?

Thanks guys for your help!

Comment: You should only HtmlEncode data when displaying it, not when storing it. In other words, store it un-encoded and only encode it when displaying it.

Comment: I do not agree with that. Encoded User's input and store in Data can prevent a Maliciousness user to modify the Data Base. By the way any idea to my original question? :-) thanks

Comment: Encoding does not do anything to protect the database at all.

Comment: As long as you use parameterized queries (which you should be doing) there is no risk of SQL injection and no need to encode the data you are storing. You need to learn this before there is any point answering your question as it based on a mistaken belief.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your comment I appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I would say that you should never encode before storing in a database. You encode at the point of output - before you put it in a text box, or a grid or wherever.

This has a few advantages;

1. You're format agnostic - you can take your data and put it as HTML, XML, JSON or whatever because you haven't locked yourself to a single format when storing.
2. It makes search easier, if you're searching those fields.
3. If there is a bug in the Encode function you're using you may end up storing unsafe values. By encoding at the point of output you could replace your encoder with a non-buggy one, or one using a blacklist rather than a whitelist without having to go through all your data, pulling it out, decoding it and re-encoding it.

In the case of textbox the actual encoding depends on the type of textbox - a single line text box is attribute encoded, a multiline text box is HTML encoded, and using the text property of the asp.net textbox control encodes for you, using the correct method.

By storing "raw" HTML you remove the need to decode because the controls are encoding automatically for you, there is nothing for you to centralise.

Comment: OK I understand your point, but my Data Base has all the content ENCODED. So I need find a way to DECODE the result when displaying to the user using a TextBox in a GridView in Edit Mode. Any idea how to solve it? Many thanks!

Comment: Aside from going through the database once, decoding everything and then storing it again? That's your proper solution here.